# Error occured in implementations of "chilkat" library

Tags: chilkat

i want to implement chilkat in android project. I read chilkat whole documentation and followed all steps. even i have also loaded chilkat library succefully but whenever i call any function of chilkat  then i  get an error of** "No implementation found for void chilkatsoft.chilkatJNI.swig_module_init() (tried Java_chilkatsoft_chilkatJNI_swig_1module_1init and Java_chilkatsoft_chilkatJNI_swig_1module_1init__)"**..
i'm attaching one snapshot of error with this mail.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wdOe.png)
can you please tell me solution of this issue?